# How to detect First run of the application after installation?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to catch first run of the application after installation. I know that I can use user settings. for example:

```
if(Properties.Settings.Default.CheckFirstTime == true)
{
     MessageBox.Show("1st run");
     Properties.Settings.Default.CheckFirstTime = false;
     Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
else
{
     MessageBox.Show("Later run");
}
```

But in this case, it is not possible to catch first run when the user uninstalls and reinstalls the application again.
Also, I don't want to use a database, because it may be replaced with a manipulated database.

What's the best way to ensure catching the first run of the application after installation?

Comment: Answers to this question will be primarily opinion based. There will almost always be a work around for any solution you come up with. Give the right person enough time and they will figure a way around it.

Comment: my users are not hackers but they may uninstall and reinstall the program .

Comment: My first guess would have been a RegistryKey. Not really a big deal, but for "Joe Average-User" most of the time enough.

Comment: how can I add a RegistrKey?

Comment: For "how can I add a RegistrKey" -- check for existing questions, because people will have answered that already with very well written answers.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your installation method, it could be worth using the registry for this.

When the program is initially installed, there will be no registry keys to store the properties.
If they are not present, write them into the registry as it's assumed to be the first run.

Using this approach, the keys will not be removed when uninstalling as the program manages them itself rather than allowing the installer to handle it.

The following link describes interacting with the registry in C#.
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3389/Read-write-and-delete-from-registry-with-C

If you're using MSI for the installer package, you can configure it to leave behind the registry data when uninstalling, which will work around the issue. This is configured differently depending on the tool you use to create the MSI, but as it's supported by the format, it should be implemented in most installation builders than support generating an MSI.

If using install shield, the following section of the documentation describes how to create and remove registry keys - http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield23helplib/helplibrary/IHelpRegistryKeys.htm

Comment: I use InstallShield to create msi  project. do you know how can I use it?

Comment: I'm not certain how to apply this in install shield, however the documentation should cover registry changes. The second option I have outlined would be a more self contained solution. Personally, I would use the second approach as you have more control over how the registry keys are handled.

Comment: @Behnam You can find more information on [Flexerasoftware](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/isxhelp21/helplibrary/IHelpRegistryKeys.htm)